Calcuating the monthly stock of opened items in Mysql
I'm having a hard time with this query, thanks in advance for the help!
Given a set of items with opened and close date I need to calculate the count of opened items for each months (all items not yet closed before the end of the month)
I'm attaching an example below with some dates, the desired outcome would look something like this



Month
Stock




Sep 2012
0


Oct 2012
4


Nov 2012
4


Dec 2012
2


Jan 2013
3


Feb 2013
0


Mar 2013
0



I have created a fiddle with this example
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kBFviS9ZjMWdXR8aeZ3bDk/1
I'm using
Mysql 5.7.44-log
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disbled
CREATE TABLE TestDate (
    Objectid int,
    OpenDate date NULL,
    CloseDate date NULL
);

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(1, '2013-02-18 00:00:00', '2013-02-19 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(2, '2013-01-22 00:00:00', '2013-01-28 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(3, '2012-10-17 00:00:00', '2013-02-01 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(4, '2012-10-28 00:00:00', '2012-12-14 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(5, '2013-01-16 00:00:00', '2013-02-02 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(6, '2013-01-20 00:00:00', '2013-01-25 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(7, '2012-11-25 00:00:00', '2012-12-04 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(8, '2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-04 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO TestDate(Objectid, OpenDate, CloseDate) 
    VALUES(9, '2012-10-31 00:00:00', '2012-11-15 00:00:00');

I have tried many aproaches with different ideas from arround stackoverflow but none of them seem to create the desired outcome

If you're using MySQL 8.x I think you should be able to do this using window functions.

"I have tried many aproaches" -- please post what you think is your closest attempt. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Although maybe there is a reason, wouldn't it be better to pass a NULL annd set to  Auto Increment that first value and make it a primary key perhaps for dynamic use?

It's essentially a kind of running total, so research solutions to that.

In MySQL the only problem is year-month list generation. Then it must be joined to the data table by the condition last_day_of_month BETWEEN start AND finish and grouped by year-month.

This example uses the sequence in derived table seq to generate the list of last days of each month in derived table months and then joins to your TestDate table.
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(months.eom, '%b %Y') AS Month, COUNT(td.Objectid) AS Stock
FROM (
    SELECT LAST_DAY('2012-09-01' + INTERVAL seq.n MONTH) AS eom
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) seq
) months
LEFT JOIN TestDate td ON months.eom >= td.OpenDate
                     AND (months.eom < td.CloseDate OR td.CloseDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY months.eom;

Here's a db<>fiddle.
If you do not need to account for situations where there is no CloseDate set, then you can drop the OR td.CloseDate IS NULL.
